# How can a piece of steel rotated without any power input?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering, kinematics

Currently I am trying to rotate a piece of steel >90 degrees without any power input. The piece of steel is attached on the wall. A servo is also attached on the steel.

This question addresses turning the piece of steel if the servo fails to work. A battery is not supposed to be used. Generally like a servo may do it with power the rotation should be performed without power whilst in this case the rotation has to take place only once.
The trigger is a toggle switch that will drop,if pushed, a weight on the right side (see picture) in order to rotate the piece of steel. This rotation has only to be performed once. Doing this currently the required rotation >90 degree does not take place.

The remaining questions are:

1. Where has the weight to tip the steel ideally so that the piece of steel can be moved/rotated with the least amount of force? I was thinking that the edge of on the right side of the steel would be most beneficial location to tip with the weight. Am I right?
2. What weight must ‘the object’ be in order to move a 8cm x 2cm x 4cm piece of steel >90 degrees. Hereby I have to know the required force on the steel in order to rotate it.

Do I think too naively and have any mistake on my thoughts?

[image]

Comment: are you allowed to use gravity as a power source?

Comment: @ratchet freak  yes I am

Comment: Is there some sort of input mechanism to tell the piece when to rotate (a button or something)? When should it rotate?

Comment: The trigger is not determined yet..so therefore free to design...I was thinking of a button as well. As long as it may work without any power a button can be utilized

Comment: I'm putting this on hold as it essentially asks us to [design your solution](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/188/41) for you. I suggest you narrow the scope of the question once you have identified a potential design either on your own or through other means such as our [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20403/the-skunk-works). For example, determining the weight you would need to tip the steel with a certain type of movement would be on-topic, provided you could show the design and point to a variable in it you needed to determine.

Comment: Your edit to the question helps, but I'm unclear as to what you really asking. Do you want help deciding on how the piece could be moved or are you asking for calculations of how much force it would take?  Please specifically clarify the bulleted questions.

Comment: If I am understanding this right, you need to use mechanical leverage to rotate a steel block about some fixed axis, and the rotation must be greater than 90 degrees. The leverage takes the form of a dropped weight. If that is correct, the question is still too broad. What restrictions are there on placement of the fixed axis with respect to (wrt) the block (e.g. what lever arm is available)? What orientation is the block wrt the servo? Where is the wall in the diagrams (behind the block, or under the block)? Can the block have components added to extend leverage?

Comment: ...Does the servo provide frictional resistance? How much resistance?

Comment: @starrise thx. I will come up soon with a new detailed question disclosing all required information....

Comment: Also, the given image is odd. If you drop a weight on top of the steel piece, it will never rotate. If the axis of rotation is where the piece is connected to the servo, then dropping the weight right on top of the servo will also never rotate since there is no lever arm.